# i3 window manager - put MATLAB figure window in specific workspace

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm using i3 as window manager in Ubuntu 12.04. I work a lot with MATLAB, and I started wondering if there is a way to make i3 put my figures in a specific workspace each time I plot something. I've read parts of the i3 user-guide but couldn't figure out a way to do this.

Comment: I don't know i3 (but by the sound of it, I sure am going to try it :), but I imagine it's only possible if you modify/customize i3 in such a way that every window of the MATLAB figure class is managed in a different way than the default...I suspect that it's possible to configure/script this somehow into i3? In any case, don't expect MATLAB to be capable of this sort of thing in any sort of convenient way; it was not built with tiling WMs in mind.

Comment: Wait, I have an idea...I need to know: if you open a new figure, what happens to it? Does it get tiled automatically, or is it treated like a dialog? If it gets tiled, what does its `get(gcf, 'position')` get set to? And `get(gcf, 'WindowStyle')`? What happens to those values when you move the figure to another workspace?

Comment: The figure is automatically tiled within the focused container, and the position is automatically set to the position of the current tile. (using set(gcf,'position',posVector) only has an effect when the window is in floating mode). get(gcf,'WindowStyle') returns 'normal'

Comment: So manually setting the figure position has no effect at all?

Comment: And what's the position do when you put it on another workspace?

Comment: When it is in tiling mode the set(gcf,'position',aPosition) has no effect, but the position ( get(gcf,'position') ) changes when I change the layout of the tiles. e.g. when I move the figure to my other monitor which is set vertical

Comment: Hmmm...nope, then my idea won't work. You'll have to customize your i3 somehow, because apparently you can't override window placement from within MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to put the following in my .i3/config:

```
assign [class="com-mathworks-util-PostVMInit" title="^Fig"] 2
```

This makes all Figure windows from MATLAB appear in workspace 2.
The string "com-mathworks-util-PostVMInit" is the class name of the MATLAB figure which I found using the xprop terminal command.

To make sure that it's only the figure windows in MATLAB that's behaving this way I've also added title="^Fig", to seperate from other MATLAB windows.

Comment: my question here directly points two projects using matlab https://faq.i3wm.org/question/6175/how-to-make-the-new-window-popout-from-the-workspace-where-it-is-called/  while it is unsolved yet.